# Get AVR with gcc running on fedora

Tags: linux, gcc, fedora, avr, atmega

im trying to solve this issue for a few days now and i cant find any solution. 
I got myself an Atmega88A and i want to program it on fedora. 
I tried to program C with gcc and that went well. But as i tried to include the avr/io.h, i always get the failure that it didnt found anything. I tried to get the new version of gcc, but that gives me an error too. Would it be enough to just download the avr/io.h library and implement it somewhere in my files? or is there any way to download this all together, including also all the other libraries that i need (e.g. util/delay.h)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a version of GCC that is specifically built to target AVR chips, you cannot just use the normal `gcc` executable for your system because it will produce the wrong kind of program.  If you download a correctly-configured toolchain, then lines like `#include <avr/io.h>` should work automatically because the toolchain's default include search paths will be set up properly.

Many Linux distributions provide an `avr-gcc` package that you can just install with your package manager, including Fedora.  You might have to install the `avr-libc` package to get the `avr/io.h` header.

If that doesn't work for some reason, you could try downloading Microchip's official AVR toolchain from this page:

http://www.microchip.com/avr-support/avr-and-arm-toolchains-(c-compilers)

Comment: I don't use fedora myself, but pretty sure they have avr-gcc packages https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packages_For_Embedded_Development#Atmel_AVR

Comment: Example Fedora 27 : Available "avr-" →  `avr-binutils avr-gcc avr-gcc-c++ avr-libc` http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/27/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/a/

Comment: thanks, ill try downloading GCC.  Seems like it all fails when i want to download gcc-libc. It alwys says "Wrong C Compiler found, check the PATH". But i got just gcc installed, could that be the issue, that the version of gcc is simply just wrong?

How do i find out what i need then?

Comment: Please edit your question to include Fedora version. ... Install "avr" : `# dnf install avr-binutils avr-gcc avr-gcc-c++ avr-libc` About `avr/io.h` : The path is `/usr/avr/include/avr/io.h` ... ... ( Provided by  'avr-libc' ). Please set `-I/usr/avr/include`

Comment: Jonny:  please include the exact command you ran and the full output from it so I can have more clues about the error.  Also, what AVR tools did you install and how did you install them?

Comment: I can't help with specific error messages unless you provide the details of your system and what you tried.  Please remember that a download that is just called "gcc-libc" would not have anything to do with AVR microcontrollers.

Comment: Alright, thanks for all your answers, now i've got a bit further. Most of the packages I had already installed (everyone in dnf) and I now can compile my program and get an 'a.out' to execute.
But it gives me a warning that [In file included from AVR.c:1:0:
/usr/avr/include/avr/io.h:623:6: warning: #warning "device type not defined" [-Wcpp]
 #    warning "device type not defined"]

Btw sorry for not giving my Info: I've got fedora 27_64 installed with 4.14 Kernel. 
Didnt got to the avrdude writing part though

Comment: When invoking avr-gcc, you should pass an argument to indicate what chip you are compiling for.  For example `-mmcu=atmega88a`.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/AVR-Options.html   Again, if you want help with specific error messages you need to give more details about what you are doing; in this case the full command you used to compile your program would have been helpful because I still don't know if you are using `gcc` or `avr-gcc` and what options you passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

What fixed this problem for me was this missing package: `avr-gcc-c++`. Running the command:

```
dnf install avr-gcc-c++
```

fixed it.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).